# PlaySound() function isn't working

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, audio

I have been looking for over an hour through page after page of google results trying to solve this issue.

I am trying to get the PlaySound() function to work, but I cannot for the life of me get it to.

Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("E:\\Audio\\Sounds\\beep.mp3"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I have also added winmm.lib to my additional dependencies in order to fix a problem with the above code not compiling.

I have tried every combination of things that I have seen, and I cannot figure out why this will not work.  It sounds like when the program starts that windows is playing a warning sound (its the windows 7/8 default "Asterisk" sound if you go to your system sounds settings), which is NOT the beep.mp3 sound I'm trying to get it to play.

In other words, it sounds like some sort of error is occurring.  But if every time the function returns a '1', and according to MSDN that means it ran successfully.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: You need to use .wav files with this API, not mp3's.

Comment: Still didn't work after converting it and changing the filename in the code :(

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced the same issue  after changing   speaker's configuration (  Control Panel - > Hardware and Sound -> Manage audio devices   ) to quadraphonic or stereo its working fine (first it was 5.1 surround)